# Python Program won't run in IDLE but runs in terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-idle, python-venv

I wrote a program in Python (PyCharm IDE) and have a *VENV*. When I run it in the terminal after activating the *venv* or in PyCharm (still a terminal) it works perfectly as expected.
I have a few third party libraries that I use like `panda` and I believe `xlsx`. When I try to run `main.py` from *IDLE* (by loading up that file) it just lets me know that it *can't find import pandas*. Is there anyway to run this program I wrote on *IDLE*? Supposedly that's a requirement of the task. I'm using Python3 I believe. *IDLE* is v3.8 I believe.

I have a `main.py` and 2 `.py` files that I have implemented. Then another file (Excel Sheet) that I import data from and manipulate.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I didn't post a code sample cause I don't see how it would be useful in this situation but please let me know if it's needed!

Comment: have you configured your python environment in the IDLE ?

Comment: Are you starting idle from the venv?

Comment: @sahasrara62 How do I do that? Couldn't find proper documentation on that!

Comment: @strubbly how do I do that? I was looking for documentation but couldn't find anything so official. and when I try to use the IDLE command prompt, it doesn't like things like activating the venv from what it seems like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start the venv from the terminal and then run:

```
python -m idlelib.idle
```

On macOS `brew install python-tk` will install *tk* which will allow idle to open.

Comment: I saw that a few different places but everytime I try to run it (even after activating my venv) is `** IDLE can't import Tkinter.
Your Python may not be configured for Tk. **` - I use a MAC. I also need to run it on Windows. Not sure what is going on with that

Comment: @thatdevop On mac try to run: ```brew install python-tk
```